# Jackson: How to add custom metadata to a xml tag

Tags: java, xml, jackson-databind

I am trying to convert JSON to XML using Jackson. I have the following POJO

```
@Data
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Person {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String type = "student";

}
```

The following is the output after conversion:-

```
<Person>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>abc</name>
    <type>student</type>
</Person>
```

But what I want the output to be is:

```
 <Person>
    <id>1</id>
    <name type="student">abc</name>
</Person>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Any help is much appreciated. Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use @XmlAttribute:

```
@XmlAttribute
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
private String method;
```

See here: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/794/667375029